# GET Request works with cUrl but not in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios

I am trying to set up a request in Axios.
The request works perfectly with cUrl:

```
curl 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=COALINDIA' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Cookie: any' --compressed
```

however I can't make it work with Axios (on the same server).
Here is my request in Node:

```
var axiosOptions = { 
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=COALINDIA',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      timeout: 30000,
      headers: { 
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
            Cookie: 'any' 
      } 
}

await axios(axiosOptions)
```

It waits for the timeout to send the following exception

```
Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded
    at createError (/var/www/api/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/var/www/api/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:217:16)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
    at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 30000,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'User-Agent':
 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36',
Cookie: 'any' },
     method: 'get',
     url: 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=COALINDIA',
     responseType: 'arraybuffer',
     data: undefined },
  code: 'ECONNABORTED',
  request:
   Writable {
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
objectMode: false,
highWaterMark: 16384,

...

_header:
 'GET /api/quote-equity?symbol=COALINDIA HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36\r\nCookie: any\r\nHost: www.nseindia.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
_onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
agent: [Agent],
socketPath: undefined,
timeout: undefined,
method: 'GET',
path: '/api/quote-equity?symbol=COALINDIA',
_ended: false,
res: null,
...
```

What am I doing wrong in Axios?

Comment: Curl is different from AJAX, it is probably rejecting you because of cors.

Comment: Did you try with response type as application/json??? Or just don't mention any response type at all and see in axios.

Comment: cURL is asking for a compressed response. Try adding `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'` to the request headers.

Comment: I've tried removing response type and adding headers: {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'}
Doesn't work!

Comment: I suspect CORS is the reason. Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: @MattPi Did you find the solution ? I am facing similar issue, works a GET request in curl , browser & postman but not in axios.

Comment: @Rupjyoti
No! I ended up using curl directly in node (npm curl-request)

Comment: @MattPi Thanks for the update. I will try curl-request for now.

Comment: Add `'Accept': '*/*'` in `axiosOptions headers` and evaluate `responseType` @MattPi

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be not in the above given code, the root cause might be from the external API to which you are trying to connect. (the response time it took)

Which the API has failed to respond back within 30,000ms (30 seconds)

Please check for the actual time taken to get the error back from the API request by logging the time before and after performing the API request.

FYI:
Error itself mentions about the issue, `Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded`